# Pass a parameter to a method using PHP custom MVC

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

Im using a custom MVC in PHP

I have two tables.

Controles and professors

**professors** table contains an id of course --> id_professor

**controles** table contains a field called --> id_professors in which I store a list of profs ids this way ==> 1;2;5;9

In my datatable Im retrieving a list of controles from **controles** table

for **the Model**, Im using this class

```
public function fetchControlesListe(){
    stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM controles ");      
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();       
}
```

**Controller**

**liste_controles.php**

```
class Liste_Controles extends Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
        $this->view->fetchCtrlListe= $this->model->fetchControlesListe();
        $this->view->render('liste_controles/index');
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>                                                
            <th>N°</th>
            <th>Module</th>             
            <th>Salle</th>
            <th>Surveillants</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($this->fetchCtrlListe AS $key=>$value): ?>
    <tr>                                                
        <td><?php echo $controle['id_controle']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $controle['intitule_module']; ?></td>            <
        <td><?php echo $controle['intitule_salle'];?></td>
        <td>
            <?php foreach($this->prof as $profs): ?>
```

> HERE, I would like to retrieve the list of profs from **professors**
>   table and the field **id_profs** in **professors** table stores an
>   array, as i said before, containing a list of ids (Ex: **1;2;3;4;5**)
>   I would like to loop through that array and retrieve the name of
>   professor from **professors** table if the id_professor Exists in that array
>   . I know I have to create another METHOD but The PROBLEM is i don't know how to pass parameters in the method and call it from the controller to pass it to the view . and the param would be  **$controle['id_professor']**

```
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result would be like this:

[image]

**EDIT**:

> I know that is not a good idea to store lots of ids as an array, but
>   my question I just want to know how to do a foreach loop inside
>   another foreach loop using another method with a paramater that will
>   be passed from the first loop

Comment: A good first step would be to normalize your database so that it would be much simpler and efficient to retrieve data. Having this kind of things (1;2;5;9) is not really cool and does not allow you to manage your data properly. For more, you can have a look at this http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: I know right, but this time I have to do this since i'm obliged to

Comment: Forget about the 1;2;5;6; array thingy.
I just want to know how to do a foreach looop inside another foreach loop using another method with a paramater that wil be passed from the first loop

Comment: IMO, you should be exploding the list of ids in `fetchControlesListe` and fetching the professor rows there. NOT in your template. Your template should just loop data that is 100% ready to display. Don't parse and fetch data from a template, then you have poor separation of responsibilities and it is pointless to use the "MVC" pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one solution but what you can do is, because you know that id_professors is a string composed of ids separated by commas, you can retrieve an array of identifiers this way :

```
$ids = explode(",", $profs[id_professors']);
```

and then

```
<?php foreach($this->prof as $profs): ?>
   <?php $ids = explode(",", $profs['id_professors']); ?>
   <?php foreach($ids as $id): ?>
      //DO STUFF with $id
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Notice that the entire thing is not very beautiful because of opening/closing php tags constantly but I hope you'll make a wonderful templates system for your MVC framework :)

From there, **it would not be that nice to access the database directly from the view** so a better (not perfect) solution would be to provide the view an array made of professors like this one :

```
$this->view->profs_list = array(
1 => "Prof 1",
2 => "Prof 2",
//etc.
);
```

with the key of the array being the profs' identifier.

Then you can retrieve their name through the loop :

```
<?php foreach($this->prof as $profs): ?>
   <?php $ids = explode(",", $profs['id_professors']); ?>
   <?php foreach($ids as $id): ?>
      <span><?php echo $this->profs_list[$id]; ?></span><br />
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: yeah , i know this, but my problem is i know know to how to create that method and call it from the controller to pass that value in it
I mean : I Want to Retrieve Value From Foreach Loop In Controller to fetch the name of professor from another table u see what i mean? look at the picture i posted

Comment: I know, its not that big deal since Im just working o exam project of final exam and this app will be neglected later :)

Comment: I did edit the content above, tell me if it's useful

Comment: And what it is the method I should make  that contain the id_prof as parametre to loop throught those ids?

Comment: my problem is not  how to do a foreach loop or how to explode that array to get the ids... my problem is how to make the method which have a parameter to pass that id_prof into it to retrieve profs data from professors table..?

$this->prof i put there is just an example not i method I already created.. I wanto to know how to create that method ! Yous ee what i mean?